# Nested array of objects filtering returns undefined in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

I am trying for each product check if tags array of objects has at least one tag of shows.

```
const allProducts = this.products.forEach(product =>
        product.tags.some(item => item.tagName !== 'shows'),
      )
```

Data sample:

```
    Products: [
    {
    productId:...
    productName: ...
    tags:[
    {
    tagId:...
    tagName:...
    }
    {
    tagId:...
    tagName:...
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    productId:...
    productName: ...
    tags:[
    {
    tagId:...
    tagName:...
    }
    {
    tagId:...
    tagName:...
    }
    ]
    }

]
```

It seems after some() it doesn't work. What is wrong and how can be it fixed?

Comment: `Array#forEach` is a function that only *executes* what is inside the function block (i.e. after the `product => ` part). `Array#some` only returns a boolean, but does not transform the collection on which it was invoked. I think you are looking for a combination of `filter` & `some`: `const allProducts = this.products.filter(product => product.tags.some(item => item.tagName !== 'shows'));`

Comment: @nbokmans I need to return true if all products have that nested value, the filter will filter while I need to pass it for all items.

Comment: In that case I think you may be looking for `Array#every` instead of `Array#some` - `every` will only resolve to `true` if *all* items in the array match your predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly,** [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not return anything. So you should use `.filter` instead.

> for each product check if the tags array of objects has at least one tag
> of shows.

**Secondly,** the condition should be `===` instead of `!==`, Besides, `need return the true if all products are passing the some() not filter`

**==> Solution:**

```
const allValidProducts = this.products.filter(product => product.tags.some(item => item.tagName === 'shows'));
const result =  allValidProducts.length === this.products.length;
```

So as you can see, the [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) works fine.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(array.some(element => element % 2 === 0));
// expected output: true
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const allProducts = this.products.filter(product => product.tags.some(item => item.tagName !== "shows")).length == allProducts.length;
```

All products pass `some` if the length of the filtered array remains unchanged.

Comment: This will return an array of booleans instead of filtered products. Besides, `filter` also creates a new array.

Comment: How can I return boolean if all items are boolean instead of array of booleans?

Comment: @expressjs123 I need return the true if all products are passing the some() not filter